# Билдер тела для запросов на Python

Tags: python

Пытаюсь написать билдер для отправки запросов на сервер:
Есть вот такое:

```
class ProfileUpdate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = {}

    def set_auth_token(self, auth_token):
        self.result["auth_token"] = auth_token
        return self

    def set_profile(self, name, age):
        self.result["profile"] = Profile(name, age).build_profile()
        return self

    def build_body(self):
        return self.result


class Profile:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.result = {}

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.result["name"] = name
        return self

    def set_age(self, age):
        self.result["age"] = age
        return self

    def build_profile(self):
        return self.result
```

Если запустить в таком виде:

```
body = ProfileUpdate().set_auth_token("token").set_profile("alex", "20").build_body()
```

Получаю:

```
{'auth_token': 'token', 'profile': {}}
```

А хотелось:

```
{'auth_token': 'token', 'profile': {'name': 'alex', 'age': '20'}}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся?
И как можно доработать, так что бы можно было не билдить вложенные поля, например на:

```
body = ProfileUpdate().set_auth_token("token").set_profile("alex").build_body()
```

получать:

```
{'auth_token': 'token', 'profile': {'name': 'alex'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

В классе `Profile` вы выставляете поля класса `name` и `age`, но никак их не используете. А методы `set_name` и `set_age`, изменяющие значения в словаре, который вы потом возвращаете, вы просто не вызываете.

> И как можно доработать, так что бы можно было не билдить вложенные поля

Используйте для функции значения по умолчанию. Есть и другие варианты, если вы хотите произвольный набор полей, то можно было бы использовать обобщённое название именованных аргументов `**kvargs` и работать с ним. Я ограничился вариантом с дефолтными значениями `None` для фиксированного списка аргументов функции.

Переделанный код:

```py
class ProfileUpdate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = {}

    def set_auth_token(self, auth_token):
        self.result["auth_token"] = auth_token
        return self

    def set_profile(self, name=None, age=None):
        self.result["profile"] = Profile(name, age).build_profile()
        return self

    def build_body(self):
        return self.result


class Profile:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.result = {}
        self.set_name(name)
        self.set_age(age)

    def set_name(self, name):
        if name is not None:
            self.result["name"] = name
        return self

    def set_age(self, age):
        if age is not None:
            self.result["age"] = age
        return self

    def build_profile(self):
        return self.result

body = ProfileUpdate().set_auth_token("token").set_profile("alex", "20").build_body()
print(body)

body = ProfileUpdate().set_auth_token("token").set_profile("alex").build_body()
print(body)
```

Вывод:

```
{'auth_token': 'token', 'profile': {'name': 'alex', 'age': '20'}}
{'auth_token': 'token', 'profile': {'name': 'alex'}}
```